# How to show invisible buttons after clicking on checkbox in php?

Tags: php

I am using php to connect to a database and show all rows of a table as a table on a webpage. Now  what i want is to have a checkbox and a hidden button in each row so that when i click on a checkbox in a row then corresponding button of that row become visible and when i click on that button the row will get deleted.

This is my code of php. I am using wordpress and since wordpress do not allow php on pages so i am using a plugin shortcode-exec-php to enable php on wordpress pages. But i think it is more of a programming question than wordpress support question.

```
// Connect to the database
$dbLink = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'abc', '123', 'test');
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
} 
// Query for a list of all existing files
$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `name`, `mime`, `size`, `created` FROM `file`';
$result = $dbLink->query($sql);
// Check if it was successfull
if($result) {
 // Make sure there are some files in there
if($result->num_rows == 0) {
    echo '<p>There are no files in the database</p>';
}
else {
    // Print the top of a table
    echo '<table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td><b>Name</b></td>
                <td><b>Mime</b></td>
                <td><b>Size (bytes)</b></td>
                <td><b>Created</b></td>
                <td><b>&nbsp;</b></td>
            </tr>';
    // Print each file
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "
            <tr>
                <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                <td>{$row['mime']}</td>
                <td>{$row['size']}</td>
                <td>{$row['created']}</td>
                <td><a href='get_file.php?id={$row['id']}'>Download</a></td>
               //here i want a code that insert a checkbox and a hidden button with                             the above mentioned functionalty
             </tr>";    
}
    // Close table
   echo "</table>";
}
// Free the result
$result->free();
}
else 
{
echo 'Error! SQL query failed:';
echo "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
} 
// Close the mysql connection
$dbLink->close();
```

Can anybody help me?

And if you mention javascript then tell me a way to use it with existing code.

Comment: Anything you want to happen on a webpage without reloading has to be done with Javascript.

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code which might help you(Using jquery):

**Php:**

```
 echo "
        <tr>
            <td>{$row['name']}</td>
            <td>{$row['mime']}</td>
            <td>{$row['size']}</td>
            <td>{$row['created']}</td>
            <td><a href='get_file.php?id={$row['id']}'>Download</a></td>
             <td><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox'><input type='button' style='display:none' value='delete' name='delete'><input type='button' style='display:none' value='edit'  name='edit'></td>
         </tr>";
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function () {
   ($(this).is(":checked")) ? $(this).nextAll("input").show() : $(this).nextAll("input").hide();
 });
 $("input[name='delete']").on("click", function () {
   $(this).closest("table tr").remove();
 });
   $("input[name='edit']").on("click", function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").attr("contenteditable",true).focus();
  });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hctyP/2/

Comment: Thanks Joke but it is my mistake that i didn't ask full question. Actually i want to have two buttons delete and edit. Your solution works for delete only.How can i use edit in the same way. And one thing i want to update database also on clicking on delete and edit.

Comment: Check my updated fiddle..I added edit option..:)And use ajax to update your database on delete or edit.

Comment: ok Thanks but one more thing how can i know which row's delete button is clicked to use in ajax for updating database

Comment: While displaying each rows in while loop also display the unique id of that record in input type `hidden`,while deleting get that unique id.In that way  you can compare unique id  with the primary key of that table and delete the corresponding row.

Comment: sorry joke but i am not able to do it can you help me with this. i am newbie in php jquery. how can i get the row id? how i can pass it to ajax. nothing working